# How do I print the last output only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def cubroot(n):
    for p in range(n):
        if n>p*p*p:
            d=n-(p*p*p)
            print(p,"not exact with differnece",d)
        elif (p*p*p)==n:
            return print(p,"exact!")
    pass

cubroot(2000)
```

output:

```
0 not exact with differnece 2000
1 not exact with differnece 1999
2 not exact with differnece 1992
3 not exact with differnece 1973
4 not exact with differnece 1936
5 not exact with differnece 1875
6 not exact with differnece 1784
7 not exact with differnece 1657
8 not exact with differnece 1488
9 not exact with differnece 1271
10 not exact with differnece 1000
11 not exact with differnece 669
12 not exact with differnece 272
```

de-denting the print is breaking the loop

Answer (score 2):

Set a variable instead of printing. Use `break` to stop the loop rather than `return`.

Then print the variable at the end.

```
def cubroot(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif range < 0:
        n = -n
    for p in range(n):
        if n>p*p*p:
            d=n-(p*p*p)
            result = f"{p} not exact with difference {d}"
        elif (p*p*p)==n:
            result = f"{p} exact"
            break
    print(result)
```

Comment: but why cubroot(0) is returning Error? thanks !

Comment: Because `range(0)` is empty, so it never sets `result`.

Comment: I've added checks for 0 and negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You should not return print statements: return just the value you want to print and print the whole function so not this

```
return print(p,"exact!")
```

but this

```
return int(p) + " exact!"
```

Comment: You can't add a number and a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function altered to meet your requirement:

```
def cubroot(n):
    for p in range(n):
        if (n ** (1 / 3) - 1) ** 3 < p ** 3 < n:
            d = n - p ** 3
            print(p, "not exact with differnece", d)
        elif p ** 3 == n:
            return print(p, "exact!")

cubroot(2000)
```

The expression `p ** 3` is the equivalent of `p * p * p`.
I basically changed your condition

```
p ** 3 < n
```

to be

```
(n ** (1 / 3) - 1) ** 3 < p ** 3 < n
```

Another way is this:

```
def cubroot(n):
    for p in range(n):
        if p ** 3 < n and (p + 1) ** 3 > n:
            d = n - p ** 3
            print(p, "not exact with differnece", d)
        elif p ** 3 == n:
            return print(p, "exact!")

cubroot(2000)
```